# Detect where a user's cursor is and show it in another window

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

similar to google docs, I would like to be able to do the following:

- User A - Window 1 - Detect where the user's cursor is on the page, could be any number of inputs
- User B - Window 2 - Show where User A's cursor is with a dot position absolutely with top & left.

Easy enough to ask hard to get right. What happens when the user scrolls, users have different window/browser dimensions, font formatting etc.

Any clever, elegant ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Well I agree with "hard to get right" part :-)

Comment: I would calculate everything as percentages. Get the window dimensions, then convert cursor positions into percent from a standard point (maybe top left of the screen?)

Answer (score 0):

Use a library such as Rangy

http://code.google.com/p/rangy/

It can get the position of any selected text, including multiple selections.

It also can mark selections with a `<span>`, which could be useful to you

Comment: I won't be using inputs, not textareas etc... This library seems specific to that right?

Comment: @AnApprentice you "won't" be?, rangy detects selections in the DOM, not textareas

Comment: I think he's talking about the mouse cursor, not the caret.

Comment: @LeaVerou well the mouse cursor is even easier to get

Comment: @LeaVerou and I assumed it was the caret, as Google Docs shows other peoples caret, not mouse cursor